# Label doesn't dynamically expand

Tags: xaml, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App;assembly=App.Droid"
             x:Class="App.MainPage">
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
      <local:MainModel />
    </StackLayout.BindingContext>

    <Label Text="{Binding Uri}" />
    <Button Text="Clear logs" Command="{Binding LogClear}" />
    <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label FormattedText="{Binding Log}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

`Log` gets updated while the application is running, but the label doesn't expand as expected. Any idea?

Comment: try horizontaloptions="FillAndExpand" on scrollview

Comment: Can you explain does not expand as expected? What did you expect?

Comment: I expected that it expands enough to show the whole text when a new span gets added.

Comment: @173210 place stack layout around label.

Comment: @ParthPatel I tried that but it didn't make difference.

Comment: You have couple of labels, and which doesn't? If it's horizontal then you have to add, default will be start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot share the details here but it was a bug of Xamarin.Forms. Now it's fixed in upstream.